# Problemas com insert no Oracle com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oracle, sql-insert

Estou tendo um problema com um `INSERT` no Oracle utilizado o pacote [yajra/laravel-oci8](https://packagist.org/packages/yajra/laravel-oci8), onde me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Error Code : 1722 Error Message : ORA-01722: numero invalido Position
>   : 260 Statement : insert into TRANSMISSAOITBIDIGITAL (INSCRICAOIMOVEL,
>   VENDEDOR, COMPRADOR, DATALANCAMENTO, DATATRANSACAO, VLTRANSACAO,
>   VLFINANCIADO, VLNAOFINANCIADO, FINANCIADOSFH, NUGUIAITBI, SITUACAO)
>   values (:autoparam0, :autoparam1, :autoparam2, :autoparam3,
>   :autoparam4, :autoparam5, :autoparam6, :autoparam7, :autoparam8,
>   :autoparam9, :autoparam10) (SQL: insert into TRANSMISSAOITBIDIGITAL
>   (INSCRICAOIMOVEL, VENDEDOR, COMPRADOR, DATALANCAMENTO, DATATRANSACAO,
>   VLTRANSACAO, VLFINANCIADO, VLNAOFINANCIADO, FINANCIADOSFH, NUGUIAITBI,
>   SITUACAO) values (3697, 59327952553, 62298852553, 20/06/2014,
>   20/06/2014, 100000.00, 50000.00, 50000.00, S, 1/2014, 0))

esta e a função que faz o `INSERT`

```
    public static function inserir(\entidades\Transmissao $transmissao){
        DB::setDateFormat('DD/MM/YYYY');
        DB::table('TRANSMISSAOITBIDIGITAL')->insert(array(
            'INSCRICAOIMOVEL' => $transmissao->getInscricaoimovel(),
            'VENDEDOR' => $transmissao->getVendedor(),
            'COMPRADOR' => $transmissao->getComprador(),
            'DATALANCAMENTO' => $transmissao->getDataLancamento(),
            'DATATRANSACAO' => $transmissao->getDataTrasacao(),
            'VLTRANSACAO' => $transmissao->getVlTransacao(),
            'VLFINANCIADO' => $transmissao->getVlFinanciado(),
            'VLNAOFINANCIADO' => $transmissao->getVlNaoFinanciado(),
            'FINANCIADOSFH' => $transmissao->getFinanciadosfh(),
            'NUGUIAITBI' => $transmissao->getNuGuiaItbi(),
            'SITUACAO' => $transmissao->getSituacao()
        ));
    }
```

Não faço ideia de onde seja a Position 260 para achar o erro. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Esse campos data são de que tipo?

Comment: Uma coisa estranha é que os campos de type DATE ou CHAR deveriam estar entre parenteses , como a interface trata isto !?